# Como não deixar a sessão expirar no Joomla quando fecha? (ou durar mais)

Tags: php, session, joomla

Eu tenho um componente de imóveis instalado. Ele tem a opção de adicionar imóveis aos favoritos e cria uma lista, mas quando eu fecho e abro o navegador, independente de quanto tempo ficou fechado, ele apaga a lista.

Falando com o desenvolvedor ele me disse que é por causa das sessões que são apagadas. E ele não soube me ajudar. No site demo dele, quando fecha e abre novamente, não apaga a lista de favoritos.

Alguém sabe me ajudar, como fazer para o joomla não apagar a sessão quando fechar o navegador?

Obrigado!

Comment: Reformule, **mostre o código**, diga que componente é esse, etc. Não dá pra adivinhar o que está acontecendo. O desenvolvedor, ciente do código, não conseguiu, imagina se alguém aqui vai conseguir. Qualquer um que responder à sua pergunta da forma como está só vai estar chutando, e chute não ajuda a resolver nada ;)

Answer (score 0):

O jeito de se fazer isso é usando COOKIE no lugar do SESSION. Dá uma olhadinha no [Manual do PHP](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/features.cookies.php) que é sempre salvador.

Answer (score 0):

Este é o comportamento padrão do PHP, [veja aqui](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-lifetime).

Existem duas coisas distintas e que deve ser notado nas sessões, sendo ele:

- `session.cookie_lifetime` define o tempo em que o *cookie* da sessão será apagado, em segundos. O tempo de expiração do *cookie* é definido quando ele é criado, no `session_start()`, e não é atualizado! Se o valor for `0` o *cookie* ficará disponível até que o navegador seja fechado, o que é o padrão.
- `session.gc_maxlifetime` define o tempo que o arquivo da sessão será entendido como "lixo" e potencialmente será apagado, ele leva em consideração da data da última atualização do arquivo da sessão.

---

> **/!\ Isso não é recomendado!**

Se quiser que os arquivos das sessões sejam "permanentes", assim como os *cookies*, você pode simplesmente utilizar:

```
session.cookie_lifetime = 31536000
session.gc_maxlifetime = 31536000
```

Isso irá fazer com que as sessões, nas melhores das situações, estejam disponíveis por 1 ano.

---

**Agora vamos os problemas.**

A sessão é divida em duas etapas, um cookie no navegador e um arquivo no servidor.

Definindo um `gc_maxlifetime` alto irá fazer com que o servidor tenha diversos arquivos inúteis, literalmente. A inutilidade pode ocorrer por diversos fatores, o mais comum é porque o usuário apagou os cookies ou simplesmente nunca mais acessou o website.

Definir um `cookie_lifetime` alto não há problemas, *ao meu ver*, o único problema é que se torna fácil de roubar a sessão (o valor do cookie) porque somente vai expirar ano que vem.

---

**"Solução":**

Defina um `cookie_lifetime` de uma semana, por exemplo. Isso fará com que o cookie morra depois de uma semana após criado. Além disso é preciso que o conteúdo da sessão (os arquivos) também estejam presentes, para isso mude o `gc_maxlifetime` para também uma semana.

*Além disso, quando o usuário se conectar crie um novo cookie, com a mesma sessão, dessa forma irá "renovar" as uma semana do prazo para expirar o cookie, ou seja se o usuário acessar 6 dias depois ao invés de restar 1 dia irá restar novos 7 dias.*

Uma outra solução é salvar tudo em cookie e definir um tempo de expiração alto, dessa forma não será utilizado nenhuma sessão, nenhum arquivo do servidor será lido, tudo será lido no lado do cliente para ele mesmo, *mas isso varia de caso para caso*.